# Cannot use wikipedia's response JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $.getJSON({
            url:"https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=search&origin=*&srsearch=gaby&srwhat=text&srprop=snippet&format=json",
            function (result) {
                $("#display").text(result.query.search[0].title);
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="display"></p>
```

Here is the `$.getJSON()`'s [response JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=search&origin=*&srsearch=gaby&srwhat=text&srprop=snippet&format=jsonfm). I use `result.query.search[0].title` to get the title. Why `#display` element has nothing to show?

Comment: What does the debugger show at the start of the inner (succes) function?

Comment: sorry,I don't know how to debug,I'm a new fresher. But there is no error.

Comment: Interesting. It look like a syntax error, but you really created an *object method* with name `function`. Read the `$.getJSON` documentation and a JavaScript tutorial: http://eloquentjavascript.net .

Comment: RTM: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Comment: @mplungjan one more question, how can I get the pageid in this response JSON([url](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=search&gsrsearch=meaning&srprop=size%7Cwordcount%7Ctimestamp%7Csnippet&prop=info&inprop=url))?

Comment: A few hours focused on learning how to debug (set breakpoints, examine state, step through code) will make life much easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take out `url:` and the `{}` inside `getJSON()` method.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=search&origin=*&srsearch=gaby&srwhat=text&srprop=snippet&format=json",
  function(result) {
      $("#display").text(result.query.search[0].title);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="display"></p>
```

Comment: More resources on [JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/). Seeing as you are new, documentation is priceless. It may be hard to take in/understand at first, but once you learn to really break these guys down and understand all the calls... unstoppable.

Comment: Yes, thanks! And, one more question, how can I get the `pageid` in this response JSON([url](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=search&gsrsearch=meaning&srprop=size%7Cwordcount%7Ctimestamp%7Csnippet&prop=info&inprop=url))?

Comment: @Gaby: [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11922383/218196)

Comment: @FelixKling You have been a great help, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You haven't structured your call correctly.

```
$.getJSON({
    url:"https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=search&origin=*&srsearch=gaby&srwhat=text&srprop=snippet&format=json",
    function (result) {
        $("#display").text(result.query.search[0].title);
    }
});
```

You appear to be using the syntax for [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) which isn't compatible with [`$.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/). Even if it was compatible, you would be missing the correct property name for the success function.

(Your syntax creates an object with a 'url' and 'function' attribute. (I'm not sure why the function gets that name.) This object is passed to `$.getJSON()` in the url argument. jQuery converts it to a string "[object Object]" and uses that for the url. This produces a 404. `$.getJSON()` fails silently if the request fails or the response is invalid.)

Instead, use:

```
$.getJSON(
    "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=search&origin=*&srsearch=gaby&srwhat=text&srprop=snippet&format=json",
    function (result) {
        $("#display").text(result.query.search[0].title);
    }
);
```

Comment: *"you would be missing the label for the success function."* Not sure what you mean by that, but the code is syntactically valid (unfortunately). The created object has two properties: `url` and `function` (a method).

Comment: on yes! And another question, how to get the `pageid` in this response [url](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=search&gsrsearch=meaning&srprop=size%7Cwordcount%7Ctimestamp%7Csnippet&prop=info&inprop=url)?

Comment: @FelixKling I noted the auto-naming as well while you were commenting. I'm curious about that myself. Can you point to something explaining about why that works?

Comment: @Gaby There's more than one `pageid` in that response. `results.query.pages` is presented as an object. This could be iterated over via the usual means. What you're asking is not within the scope of your original question. You'd be better off submitting it as a separate question.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions